# How to assign a specific value of some binary V. as predictors in glm?

Tags: r, regression, simulation, glm, model-fitting

I want to fit a glm in R.
The predictors I am using are let's say 4 variables:
Age, Sex, HIV
But I want to fit the glm in a way that it only uses those rows of HIV which are equal to 0 and those rows of DM which are equal to 1!

```
Age<-c(21,20,12,34,19)
Sex<-c(1,1,1,0,1,0)
HIV<c(0,1,1,0,0,0)
DM<-c(1,1,1,1,0,0)
Y<-c(1,1,0,0,1,1)
data<-data.frame(Age,Sex,HIV,DM,Y)
```

model<-glm(Y~Age+Sex+???????+?????)
Should I be writing Y~Age+Sex+(data$HIV==0)+(data$DM==1), or it means that I am setting everyone to 0 and then 1?

P.S: I edited the question after Akrun answered, the initial version just had HIV, Age and Sex

Comment: Try `glm(Y ~ Age + Sex + HIV, data = subset(data, HIV == 0))`

Comment: @akrun this was a small example but in reality, I have several variables each with different amount of 0 and 1, for some I need  1s, for some I need 0s, and the number of these 0s and 1s are not the same, so practically I do not think I can subsetting the data, Or I can?

Comment: You can combine conditions with `&`, e,g., `subset(data, HIV == 0 & DM == 1)`

Comment: @GregorThomas Thanks!!